# Sophos problems with Oracle 12c & Windows 2012

Tags: windows, oracle

Has anybody had problems running Sophos on Windows 2012 systems running Oracle 12c?

Edit:
We are seeing issues with Sophos having a tremendous amount of activity that is over utilizing the resources on the server. Normally I would expected this on a database server, but we have the On-Access scanning functionality turned off.

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered. Please edit your question and add a description of the problems you're having and perhaps someone can offer assistance. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I added a little more detail.